# How to keep GPS running in backgroud without pause

Tags: android, gps, location-services

I am working on application which keep track of the user location using GPS running in a background service. 
    The problem is that when the GPS doesn't have a fix for longer period of time, it stops automatically even though I haven't called any stop function on the GPS. The GPS icon is also not there in the status bar. Then when I get out I don't receive any location points until I manually start the GPS again from the Application.

I am reinitializing the GPS with parameters **5 secs** to **1 minute** to **10 minutes** sequentially when there is no GPS fix and back to 5 secs when the GPS has a fix. I am doing this in **GpsStatusListener** interface events.
    This has been asked few times but I could not find any proper solution on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: lets pray for the dead batteries...i suggest you using alarm manager to update your location, set it to repetitive

Comment: actually I am trying to map route taken by the user when the application is running so I am using the onLocationChange event.  can you explain what can be the reason behind GPS being stopped automatically. I will try to post the code.

Comment: can this reinitialization of gps with different parameters have any effect on saving the battery?